# Faster way to unlist, compare, and separate a column of lists while maintaining row number for large data.table

Tags: r, data.table

In my `R` `data.table` I have a column `find_tla` that is a list format of capital three-letter abbreviations pulled from a text field. I want to not only make this a unique-by-row list, but also compare each abbreviation to a separate list (of 1,200 3 letter-abbreviations found at `tla_$tla`) and only keep it if it is found on that list. Then, I want to put each of the unique and approved occurrences into their own column.

Currently, I have it going through nested for loops and an if statement 
putting these separated, unique, and approved abbreviations into a separate `data.table`- but that's not necessary. I have a code that does this on a smaller scale just fine, but with a large `data.table` with over 500,000 rows it takes too long to process and I am hoping to find a faster, more efficient way to do so.

```
library(data.table)

#sample data
  test_data <- structure(
    list(  number = c(
        "INC000008561475",
        "INC000008561472",
        "INC000008561471",
        "INC000008561469",
        "INC000008561468",
        "INC000008561467",
        "INC000008561466",
        "INC000008561465",
        "INC000008561464",
        "INC000008561462",
        "INC000008561459"
      ),
      find_tla = list( 
        c("DBA", "DBA", "ORA", "DBA", "APP"),
        character(0),
        "IDM",
        "DDM",
        character(0), 
        c("UAT", "UAT","DDM", "UAT", "UAT"),
        character(0),
        character(0),
        c("APP","ORC","CDT","WEB","WEB","DBA","ORC","WEB","URL","APP","ORC","WEB","URL"),
        "APP",
        c("DBA", "DBA", "ORA", "DBA", "GDP", "OPS", "APP")
      )
    ),
    row.names = c(NA,-14L),
    class = c("data.table",
              "data.frame"))

#sample approved abbreviations list
tla_ <- structure(
  list(
    tla = c(
      "CDT",
      "DBA",
      "IDM",
      "ORC"
    )
  ),
  row.names = c("TLA"),
  class = c("data.table",
            "data.frame")
)



#sample of where I am currently storing separated abbreviations
    keep_tla <- data.table(number = test_data$number)
    keep_tla[, `:=`(r1 = "")]
    keep_tla[, `:=`(r2 = "")]
    keep_tla[, `:=`(r3 = "")]
```

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
  col=2
for (j in 1:length(test_data$find_tla)) {
     l <- unique(strsplit(unlist(test_data[j, "find_tla"]), ","))

     {
    for (i in 1:length(l))
    {
      if (length(l) == 0) {

      } else if (l[i] %in% tla_$TLA) {

      } else{
        keep_tla[j, col] <- l[i]
        col <- col + 1
      }
    }
  }
  col = 2
}
```

Right now, with the larger data set the results is multiple hours of processing time and the creation of a `data.table` `keep_tla` with unique and approved abbreviations kept in the same row they originated but now separated into the number of columns needed.

```
#current sample output
>keep_tla
             number  r1  r2  r3
 1: INC000008561475 DBA
 2: INC000008561472
 3: INC000008561471 IDM
 4: INC000008561469
 5: INC000008561468
 6: INC000008561467
 7: INC000008561466
 8: INC000008561465
 9: INC000008561464 
10: INC000008561462 ORC DBA CDT
11: INC000008561459 DBA
```

I am fine keeping this output with a more efficient code or even just adding the columns of single, approved, unique-by-row on to the end of test_data.

Comment: Please, revise your sample dataset `test_data` and the expected output `keep_tla` as they do not match. E.g.,  `INC000008561464` appears twice  in `keep_tla` while `INC000008561459` is missing. Also, `INC000008561464` doesn't have `DBA` and `CDT` in `test_data`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to answer this question. Here are two additional approaches plus a becnhmark of the different approaches.

All require that `number` is a unique key.

#### Rowwise `intersect()`

```
test_data[, .(keep_tla = list(intersect(find_tla[[1]], tla_$tla))), by = number]
```

> ```
>              number    keep_tla
>  1: INC000008561475         DBA
>  2: INC000008561472            
>  3: INC000008561471         IDM
>  4: INC000008561469            
>  5: INC000008561468            
>  6: INC000008561467            
>  7: INC000008561466            
>  8: INC000008561465            
>  9: INC000008561464 ORC,DBA,CDT
> 10: INC000008561462            
> 11: INC000008561459         DBA
> ```

The `keep_tla` column is still a list.

#### Reshape and join

OP's expected output has separate columns for the valid `tla` values.

This can be achieved by reshaping to long format, filtering for allowed `tla` values by joining with `tla_`, and reshaping to wide format again.

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
tla_[test_data[, unlist(find_tla) %>% unique(), by = number], 
     on =.(tla = V1), nomatch = NULL] %>% 
  dcast(number ~ rowid(number, prefix = "r"), value.var = "tla")
```

> ```
>             number  r1   r2   r3
> 1: INC000008561459 DBA <NA> <NA>
> 2: INC000008561464 ORC  DBA  CDT
> 3: INC000008561471 IDM <NA> <NA>
> 4: INC000008561475 DBA <NA> <NA>
> ```

Unfortunately, filtering (joining) has also removed the rows with *no* `find_tla` values. These rows need to be replenished by a second join:

```
tla_[test_data[, unlist(find_tla) %>% unique(), by = number], 
     on =.(tla = V1), nomatch = NULL] %>% 
  dcast(number ~ rowid(number, prefix = "r"), value.var = "tla") %>% 
  .[test_data[, .(number)], on = "number"]
```

> ```
>              number   r1   r2   r3
>  1: INC000008561475  DBA <NA> <NA>
>  2: INC000008561472 <NA> <NA> <NA>
>  3: INC000008561471  IDM <NA> <NA>
>  4: INC000008561469 <NA> <NA> <NA>
>  5: INC000008561468 <NA> <NA> <NA>
>  6: INC000008561467 <NA> <NA> <NA>
>  7: INC000008561466 <NA> <NA> <NA>
>  8: INC000008561465 <NA> <NA> <NA>
>  9: INC000008561464  ORC  DBA  CDT
> 10: INC000008561462 <NA> <NA> <NA>
> 11: INC000008561459  DBA <NA> <NA>
> ```

Finally, if we want to completely reproduce OP's expected result we need to replace all `<NA>` by `""`:

```
keep_tla <- tla_[test_data[, unlist(find_tla) %>% unique(), by = number], 
     on =.(tla = V1), nomatch = NULL] %>% 
  dcast(number ~ rowid(number, prefix = "r"), value.var = "tla") %>% 
  .[test_data[, .(number)], on = "number"]
for( x in names(keep_tla)) set(keep_tla, which(is.na(keep_tla[, ..x])), x, "")
keep_tla
```

> ```
>              number  r1  r2  r3
>  1: INC000008561475 DBA        
>  2: INC000008561472            
>  3: INC000008561471 IDM        
>  4: INC000008561469            
>  5: INC000008561468            
>  6: INC000008561467            
>  7: INC000008561466            
>  8: INC000008561465            
>  9: INC000008561464 ORC DBA CDT
> 10: INC000008561462            
> 11: INC000008561459 DBA
> ```

#### Data

Here, we use a modified version of `test_data` which matches the expected result:

```
test_data <- structure(
  list(  number = c(
    "INC000008561475",
    "INC000008561472",
    "INC000008561471",
    "INC000008561469",
    "INC000008561468",
    "INC000008561467",
    "INC000008561466",
    "INC000008561465",
    "INC000008561464",
    "INC000008561462",
    "INC000008561459"
  ),
  find_tla = list( 
    c("DBA", "DBA", "ORA", "DBA", "APP"),
    character(0),
    "IDM",
    "DDM",
    character(0), 
    c("UAT", "UAT","DDM", "UAT", "UAT"),
    character(0),
    character(0),
    c("APP","ORC","WEB","ORC","WEB","APP","DBA","WEB","URL","APP","CDT","WEB","URL"),
    "APP",
    c("DBA", "DBA", "ORA", "DBA", "GDP", "OPS", "APP")
  )
  ),
  row.names = c(NA,-14L),
  class = c("data.table",
            "data.frame"))
```

#### Benchmark

The OP is *hoping to find a faster, more efficient way* to process his production dataset of 500 k rows. So here is a benchmark which compares

- 3 different variants of the `intersect()` approach,
- the reshape (`dcast()`) and join approach, and
- the first part of [Alexis'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57014072/3817004) answer.

OP's double nested for loop has not been considered as the OP is looking for a faster solution.

The benchmark runs are repeated for 100, 1000, 10 k, and 100 k rows. Test data are created for each case. As two of the solutions modify the test data, each benchmark run starts with a fresh copy. The automatic check for consistency of the results has been turned off because the different approaches return structurally differing results.

```
# benchmark

all_tla <- CJ(LETTERS, LETTERS, LETTERS)[, Reduce(paste0, .SD)][1:2400]
valid_tla <- all_tla[1:1200]
tla_ <- data.table(tla = valid_tla)
library(bench)
bm <- press(
  n_rows = 10^c(2:5),
  {
    set.seed(123L)
    td0 <- data.table(
      number = seq(n_rows),
      find_tla = replicate(n_rows, list(sample(all_tla, rchisq(1000, 2), replace = TRUE)))
    )
    mark(
      insect1 = {
        td <- copy(td0)
        td[, .(keep_tla = list(intersect(find_tla[[1]], valid_tla))), by = number]
      },
      insect1u = {
        td <- copy(td0)
        td[, .(keep_tla = list(intersect(unique(find_tla[[1]]), valid_tla))), by = number]
      },
      insect2 = {
        td <- copy(td0)
        td[, .(number, keep_tla = lapply(find_tla, function(x) intersect(x, valid_tla)))]
      },
      insect3 = {
        td <- copy(td0)
        td[, find_tla := lapply(find_tla, function(x) intersect(x, valid_tla))][]
      },
      dcast = {
        td <- copy(td0)
        tla_[td[, unlist(find_tla) %>% unique(), by = number], 
             on =.(tla = V1), nomatch = NULL] %>% 
          dcast(number ~ rowid(number, prefix = "r"), value.var = "tla") %>% 
          .[td[, .(number)], on = "number"]
      },
      Alexis = {
        td <- copy(td0)
        tla <- valid_tla
        td[, (tla) := as.data.frame(t(sapply(find_tla, function(ftla) { tla %in% ftla })))]
        all_false <- td[, lapply(.SD, Negate(any)), .SDcols = tla]
        all_false <- names(which(unlist(all_false)))
        if (length(all_false) > 0L) {
          td[, (all_false) := NULL]
        }
        td[]
      },
      min_time = 2,
      check = FALSE
    )
  }
)
```

The timings can be visualised by

```
library(ggplot2)
autoplot(bm)
```

[image]

(Please note the logarithmic time scale).

The "insect" variants are significantly faster than the two other approaches and will allow to process a production dataset of 500 k rows reasonably fast.

On the other hand, if available computer memory is limited memory consumption might be a criteria to consider. Here, the "dcast" approach allocates much less memory than all other approaches while Alexis' approach is most demanding.

```
print(bm, n = Inf)
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 20 x 14
>    expression n_rows      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result    memory    time  gc    
>    <bch:expr>  <dbl> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>    <list>    <lis> <list>
>  1 insect1       100   2.21ms   2.83ms  340.        1.24MB    3.47    589     6      1.73s <data.ta~ <Rprofme~ <bch~ <tibb~
>  2 insect2       100    1.9ms   2.07ms  444.        1.24MB    3.65    851     7      1.92s <data.ta~ <Rprofme~ <bch~ <tibb~
>  3 insect3       100   2.05ms   2.25ms  406.        1.21MB    4.28    759     8      1.87s <data.ta~ <Rprofme~ <bch~ <tibb~
>  4 dcast         100  22.53ms  26.66ms   37.5     583.34KB    2.75     68     5      1.82s <data.ta~ <Rprofme~ <bch~ <tibb~
>  5 Alexis        100  36.21ms  38.12ms   25.5       5.43MB    6.03     38     9      1.49s <data.ta~ <Rprofme~ <bch~ <tibb~
>  6 insect1      1000  16.31ms  17.56ms   55.8       11.8MB    4.39     89     7      1.59s <data.ta~ <Rprofme~ <bch~ <tibb~
>  7 insect2      1000  15.07ms  16.62ms   58.0      11.79MB    3.83    106     7      1.83s <data.ta~ <Rprofme~ <bch~ <tibb~
>  8 insect3      1000  18.56ms  19.56ms   49.4      11.79MB    4.59     86     8      1.74s <data.ta~ <Rprofme~ <bch~ <tibb~
>  9 dcast        1000 107.46ms 109.64ms    9.06      1.11MB   10.2       8     9   883.43ms <data.ta~ <Rprofme~ <bch~ <tibb~
> 10 Alexis       1000  59.44ms  64.22ms   15.2      43.52MB    5.79     21     8      1.38s <data.ta~ <Rprofme~ <bch~ <tibb~
> 11 insect1     10000  159.8ms 175.13ms    5.66    114.96MB    4.71     12    10      2.12s <data.ta~ <Rprofme~ <bch~ <tibb~
> 12 insect2     10000 151.99ms 187.61ms    5.26    114.84MB    4.30     11     9      2.09s <data.ta~ <Rprofme~ <bch~ <tibb~
> 13 insect3     10000 219.12ms 272.98ms    3.45    115.12MB    3.94      7     8      2.03s <data.ta~ <Rprofme~ <bch~ <tibb~
> 14 dcast       10000 941.24ms    1.11s    0.898     7.66MB    5.84      2    13      2.23s <data.ta~ <Rprofme~ <bch~ <tibb~
> 15 Alexis      10000 624.61ms 633.59ms    1.42    424.82MB    6.13      3    13      2.12s <data.ta~ <Rprofme~ <bch~ <tibb~
> 16 insect1    100000    1.86s    1.91s    0.523     1.11GB    1.57      2     6      3.82s <data.ta~ <Rprofme~ <bch~ <tibb~
> 17 insect2    100000    2.56s    2.56s    0.391     1.11GB    0.783     1     2      2.56s <data.ta~ <Rprofme~ <bch~ <tibb~
> 18 insect3    100000    2.21s    2.21s    0.453     1.11GB    1.36      1     3      2.21s <data.ta~ <Rprofme~ <bch~ <tibb~
> 19 dcast      100000   10.34s   10.34s    0.0968   73.18MB    1.84      1    19     10.34s <data.ta~ <Rprofme~ <bch~ <tibb~
> 20 Alexis     100000   11.12s   11.12s    0.0900    4.13GB    0.540     1     6     11.12s <data.ta~ <Rprofme~ <bch~ <tibb~
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this format could work for you?

```
tla <- c("CDT", "DBA", "IDM", "ORC")

test_data[, (tla) := as.data.frame(t(sapply(find_tla, function(ftla) { tla %in% ftla })))]

all_false <- test_data[, lapply(.SD, Negate(any)), .SDcols = tla]
all_false <- names(which(unlist(all_false)))

if (length(all_false) > 0L) {
  test_data[, (all_false) := NULL]
}

test_data[]
             number                    find_tla   DBA   IDM   ORC
 1: INC000008561475         DBA,DBA,ORA,DBA,APP  TRUE FALSE FALSE
 2: INC000008561472                             FALSE FALSE FALSE
 3: INC000008561471                         IDM FALSE  TRUE FALSE
 4: INC000008561469                         DDM FALSE FALSE FALSE
 5: INC000008561468                             FALSE FALSE FALSE
 6: INC000008561467         UAT,UAT,DDM,UAT,UAT FALSE FALSE FALSE
 7: INC000008561466                             FALSE FALSE FALSE
 8: INC000008561465                             FALSE FALSE FALSE
 9: INC000008561464 APP,ORC,WEB,ORC,WEB,APP,... FALSE FALSE  TRUE
10: INC000008561462                         APP FALSE FALSE FALSE
11: INC000008561459 DBA,DBA,ORA,DBA,GDP,OPS,...  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Here, `tla` holds the approved abbreviations,
and the second line adds a column for each one,
where its value for the row will be `TRUE` if the list in the corresponding `find_tla`
contains it.
These values are obtained by using `sapply` to first apply the check to all rows' `find_tla` lists,
but since `sapply` binds column-wise,
the result must be transposed.

The lines below that are to check if some columns are all `FALSE`,
i.e. the given abbreviation was not present in any row.
Those columns are removed.

And if you definitely need the actual characters in each row,
you can add something like this afterwards:

```
remaining_tla <- setdiff(tla, all_false)
test_data[, (remaining_tla) := Map(ifelse, .SD, yes = names(.SD), no = NA_character_), .SDcols = remaining_tla]

test_data[]
             number                    find_tla  DBA  IDM  ORC
 1: INC000008561475         DBA,DBA,ORA,DBA,APP  DBA <NA> <NA>
 2: INC000008561472                             <NA> <NA> <NA>
 3: INC000008561471                         IDM <NA>  IDM <NA>
 4: INC000008561469                         DDM <NA> <NA> <NA>
 5: INC000008561468                             <NA> <NA> <NA>
 6: INC000008561467         UAT,UAT,DDM,UAT,UAT <NA> <NA> <NA>
 7: INC000008561466                             <NA> <NA> <NA>
 8: INC000008561465                             <NA> <NA> <NA>
 9: INC000008561464 APP,ORC,WEB,ORC,WEB,APP,... <NA> <NA>  ORC
10: INC000008561462                         APP <NA> <NA> <NA>
11: INC000008561459 DBA,DBA,ORA,DBA,GDP,OPS,...  DBA <NA> <NA>
```